# React Native: the app crashes when I go back from one screen to another

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I am building an application project with react native. The video of the problem:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pu15n.jpg (>2MB)

In short, the app has two separate searches, the first searches for the lyrics of a song, the second the biography of the artist. The problem is when I try to switch from the song page to the artist page, in fact going back the app crashes.

Stack Navigator on `App.js`:

```
    const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="MyMusic"
          component={TabNavigator}
          options={{
            title: 'MyMusic',
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#673AB7',
            },
            headerTintColor: 'white',
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Search song"
          component={SongScreen}
          options={{
            title: 'Search Song',
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#673AB7',
            },
            headerTintColor: 'white',
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Search artist"
          component={ArtistScreen}
          options={{
            title: 'Search Artist',
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#673AB7',
            },
            headerTintColor: 'white',
          }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

passing through Artist Info on `SongScreen.js`:

```
function SongScreen({ route, navigation }) {

//...

const RightCardContent = () => 
    <View style={{margin: '8%'}}>
      <Button
        title='ARTIST INFO'
        color='#673AB7'
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Search artist', textArtist)}
      />
    </View>

//...

return (

//...

<Card>
   <Card.Title
        title={songName}
        subtitle={artistName}
        left={LeftCardContent}
         right={RightCardContent}
    />
 </Card>

//...

)}
```

Comment: Open Android Studio and watch in Logcat your errors. https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat

Comment: @VasylNahuliak being an app developed with react native I typed in the console `adb logcat *:S ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V` and when the app crashes does not give me any error

Comment: start the android emulator from Android Studio and look below Logcat. There you will see an error

Comment: @VasylNahuliak But my app is not built on android studio, so I can't start it from there. Is there another way?

Comment: You can open Android Studio for your React Native project https://reactnative.dev/docs/_getting-started-linux-android#installing-dependencies Just open android folder in your project by Android Studio https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QqjrR11tuz0